# Webform 8 - How can I make a text field value be A if a select value is 1?

Tags: webforms

In Webform 8 I am trying to figure out how to populate a text field with a value based on what is chosen on a drop down.

For example:
Select Value are states
If user selects Deleware then the value for the text field Ratified is equal to 1.

How can I achieve this in Webform 8x?

In Webform 7x I am able to do this with the Conditionals tab but can't seem to be able to figure out how to do this in Webform 8.

Comment: Populating a text field using conditions is not supported in 8.x because 8.x uses Drupal's #states API.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use JS, go to settings - CSS/JS tab, write code in CUSTOM JAVASCRIPT textarea.

Some code for reference. I got a text input (id is edit-name), a select (id is edit-gender), the id you find enter 'F12' to see. ID is automatically generated by Webform.
When I select male, the text input will appear male.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {'use strict';$(document).ready(function(){
  'use strict';
  var name = $("#edit-name");
  var gender = $("#edit-gender");
  var duty = $("#edit-duty-select"); 
  function ab() {if (gender.val()==='male'){name.val("male");} else {name.val("girl")}};  
  gender.change(ab);  // add a Listener to select
});  
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Whilst on the face of it the ability you add some JS via the UI in this way is neat, I can't find any documentation that sets out how to make best use of it.